# cocos2d-x 3beta 2 C++, prevent touches seep through from the top most layer to the layers beneath it

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have simple layer and then I have second layer that is popup window. When I create the popup window that is layer when I touch it the touches seep through from the top most layer to the layers beneath it.

How can I prevent it, so when the popup is on top all layers beneath are untouchable? This is the touches code in the popup window:

```
void PopupLayerObj::onEnter()
{
    Layer::onEnter();

    
    auto listener = EventListenerTouchAllAtOnce::create(); 
    
    listener->onTouchesBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(PopupLayerObj::onTouchesBegan, this);
    listener->onTouchesMoved = CC_CALLBACK_2(PopupLayerObj::onTouchesMoved, this);
    listener->onTouchesEnded = CC_CALLBACK_2(PopupLayerObj::onTouchesEnded, this);
    _eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Cocos2DX 3.0 version. I am using cocos2DX 2.2.1 as per that I try to give solution.

- Override CCLayer's "registerWithTouchDispatcher" method.
- There specify priority for View.
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this, kHIGHEST_TOUCH_PRIORITY, true);
- kHIGHEST_TOUCH_PRIORITY specifies priority. Lowest value has highest priority.
- When you are done with your pop up window write this.
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->removeDelegate(this);

Comment: I am not suggesting you to use 2. I am just telling same function might be there also.